# HttpClient PostAsync Invalid Post Format

Tags: c#, httpclient

I am trying to use HttpClient's PostAsync to login to a website; However it always fails and when I tracked the connection using WireShark I found that it posts the data incorrectly

#### Code

```
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[] 
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("value1", data1),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("value2", data2),
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("value3", data3)
});
```

or

```
var content = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("value1", data1), 
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("value2", data2), 
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("value3", data3)
};
```

usage

```
httpClient.PostAsync(postUri, content)
```

#### Expectations

```
value1=123456&value2=123456&value3=123456
```

#### Reality

```
//It adds strange += which makes the post fail...
value1=123456&value2+=123456&value3+=123456
```

Comment: Is there any chance there is a space after the parameter name that is being url encoded to a `+`?

Comment: @Jason P I will recheck

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I Know this works:

```
var values = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Item1", "Value1"));
values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Item2", "Value2"));
values.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Item3", "Value3"));

using (var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values))
{
    client.PostAsync(postUri, content).Result)
}
```

Comment: but I don't see any difference between this and the code I posted, but I will give it a try

Comment: I agree, there is no difference, and that is the point, I know this code works.  You should look for differences in the values :)

Comment: :D The mistake was me not the httpClient :D as Jason P stated I was somehow have a space in my parameter names. Any way thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Trim the parameters for possible whitespaces. Whitespaces result in a +

```
var content = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
{
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("value1", data1.Trim()), 
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("value2", data2.Trim()), 
    new KeyValuePair<string, string>("value3", data3.Trim())
};
```

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion this is nicer to see:

```
var variables = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
    { "value1", value1 },
    { "value2", value2 }
};
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(variables);
```

and a dictionary can be useful to check for repeated values when loading it, unless you need repeated keys...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56090072/109941