# Why does a PostAsync() request using HttpClient throw an UnauthorizedAccessException?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-8.1, dotnet-httpclient, windows-10

I'm performing a basic POST request using `HttpClient`. Each time the request is made an `UnauthorizedAccessException` is thrown with the message

> MemoryStream's internal buffer cannot be accessed.

I've tried using a GET request without any parameters instead and that works fine, which leads me to believe that it could be my process of producing the parameters to send. Also, when the PostAsync() method is invoked from within a try/catch block, the exception is never caught by the catch block, instead, the request continues. I've never had an issue with POST requests like this before.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient()) 
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://theurl.com/");

    List<KeyValuePair<String, String>> parameters = claim.RequestParameters();
    var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(parameters);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));
    HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
    try
    {
        response = await client.PostAsync(url, content); // Exception generated here
    }
    catch (System.UnauthorizedAccessException e)
    {
        // This catch statement is never entered
        Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) // ...
}
```

I'm developing for Windows 10 (I'm using Windows 10 build 10162) and the exception is thrown on both x86 and x64 versions.

**Update 1:**

I've noticed from the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e55f3s5k.aspx) that the `MemoryStream(byte[])` constructor will throw an `UnauthorizedAccessException`.

> This constructor does not expose the underlying stream. GetBuffer throws UnauthorizedAccessException.

`MemoryStream(byte[], Int32, Int32, Boolean, Boolean)` should be used instead.

Could it be possible that the `PostAsync()` method is internally calling the `MemoryStream(byte[])` constructor instead of the `MemoryStream(byte[], Int32, Int32, Boolean, Boolean)` constructor and this is what's causing the problem?

**Update 2:**

I have also tried using a minimum example from [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17974184/4106164) where the poster of the code knows it works on his machine. It does *not* work on mine. I still have the same exception thrown as above.

Comment: Do you need to connect with credentials?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov No, it's just a plain POST with some parameters.