# unable to convert curl request to HttpClient/AnyOtherPackage in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I have a curl request, which is valid:

```
curl --insecure -X POST 'https://someurl' --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' --data-urlencode 'k1=v1' --data-urlencode 'k2=v2' --data-urlencode 'k3=v3' --data-urlencode 'k4=v4' --data-urlencode 'k5=v5'
```

I've tried multiple solutions from SO but unfortunately, I'm unable to convert it to `HttpClient` request, I'm getting a `BadRequest`. My code is:

```
        var client = new HttpClient();

        // var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        // dict.Add("k1", "v1");
        // dict.Add("k2", "v2");
        // dict.Add("k3", "v3");
        // dict.Add("k4", "v4");

        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post,
            "https://someurl");
        request.Content = new StringContent("{\"k1\":\"v1\",\"k2\":\"v2\",\"k3\":\"v3\",\"k4\":\"v4\"}",
            Encoding.UTF8,
            "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");//CONTENT-TYPE header

        request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        // request.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

        // var req = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url) { Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(dict) };
        // var res = client.SendAsync(request);
        client.SendAsync(request)
            .ContinueWith(responseTask =>
            {
                // responseTask had badrequest status in it
            });
```

Comment: You don't use StringContent for form url encoded content. [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17973981/httpclient-postasync-invalid-post-format) for an example of creating `FormUrlEncodedContent`

Comment: rest of it alright? @Crowcoder

Comment: If I were to code review it, it would fail, but SO is not for code reviews. The only actual error I noticed at a glance was the type of content you were using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be shorter :

```
var client = new HttpClient();

var data = new Dictionary<string,string>() { { "key","val"},{"key","val"},{"key","val"},{"key","val"} };

// or var data = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> { {new KeyValuePair<string, string>( "key","v")},{new KeyValuePair<string, string>( "key","v")},{new KeyValuePair<string, string>( "key","v")},{new KeyValuePair<string, string>( "key","v")}};
        
   var Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(data);

   var res = client.PostAsync("post uri",Content).Result;
        
    Console.WriteLine(res);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but still BadRequest. dont we need to add something for `--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`?

Comment: @SafiUllah `Content-Type` header is related to content not the actual request so the `FormUrlEncodedContent` takes care of it while `StringContent` is the manual approach as you should encode the content and specify the type, so this should work. make sure that your satisfying the request requirements for your endpoint.

Comment: nothing else is needed. Curl request is working properly...

Comment: thanks for your answer, it worked... Marked it as answer